# Sums of first $n$ $k$th powers which are perfect powers (as polynomials in $n$)

Tags: number-theory

This is likely a very basic question, but I have not been able to find an answer (or even someone posing this question), so here goes.

Let $P_k(n) = \sum_{m=1}^n m^k$. It is well-known that

$$\displaystyle P_3(n) = \left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2.$$

In particular, $P_3(n)$ is a perfect square as a polynomial in $n$. Is $k = 3$ the only $k$ for which this is the case? That is, does there exist $k \geq 4$ such that $P_k(n)$ is a perfect $\ell$-th power for some $\ell \geq 2$?

Comment: I do not think so but it would nice since it would be an extension of  Nicomachus's theorem.

Comment: Bernoulli gave a way to obtain general algebraic expressions for what you call $P_k(n)$ for any $k$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no other $k$.

Faulhaber's formula for $F_k(x)$ has rational coefficients and leading term $1/(k+1)$.  If $F_k(x)$ is the square of a polynomial, we have 
$$ F_k(x) = \frac{g(x)^2}{k+1}$$ 
where $g(x)^2$ is monic with rational coefficients.  Now $g(x)$, being the square root of a monic polynomial with rational coefficients, has rational coefficients (in fact the square root of a monic polynomial over the rationals can be written as a Laurent series over the rationals; it is a polynomial if the terms in negative powers of $x$ are all $0$).

In particular, 
$$ 1 + 2^k = \frac{F_k(2)}{F_k(1)} = \frac{g(2)^2}{g(1)^2} $$
is the square of a rational number, and thus the square of a positive integer $m$.  But $1 + 2^k = m^2$ means $(m-1)(m+1) = 2^k$, so both $m-1$ and $m+1$ are powers of $2$.  The only powers of $2$ that differ by $2$ are $2$ and $2^2$, which gives us the case $k=3$.